# How can i bind reference to my directive on other element?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I am watching the first example on Angular Material
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

so i want to reproduce some reusable component on my own but i can't find a way how they do that.

I don't know how they first bind the
`[matAutocomplete]="auto"`
part on the input which is connected to the reference created on the custom component `mat-autocomplete`.

So obviously they have directive called `matAutocomplete`. But when i try to reproduce the same thing i get error because i always must to have the directive setted on the same element.

For example if i have the following directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltip]',
  exportAs: 'tooltip'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
  @Input() tooltip;

}
```

and want to use outside so in the `app.component.ts` then when i try the same thing

```
<input type="text"
[tooltip]="auto" />
// Here app-autocomplete is just custom created empty component
<app-autocomplete #auto="tooltip"></app-autocomplete>
```

i get error `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "tooltip"`.
The error will go away if i set `tooltil` on the element where i want to use the directive

```
<input type="text"
[tooltip]="auto" tooltip />
<app-autocomplete #auto="tooltip" tooltip></app-autocomplete>
```

My question is how can i use the setted reference on other element ? Like they do on their example because when they use their `matAutocomplete` directive they do not set the `matAutocomplete` keyword on the same element.

Comment: Any Chance you can Post your actual component Code?  Otherwise this is going to be really hard.

Comment: @Loop the component code is empty. I just tried to attach the directive on it

Comment: Just guessing here and unable to test it, but their syntax found on https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts looks a little different, partiucarly the selector:
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-autocomplete',
I actually stumbled   over your selector at first until I realized its the offical doc way which does not make too much sense to me. Maybe try changing "selector: '[tooltip]'," to " selector: 'tooltip',"?